# Splitting a CSV into multiple files based on value of first column, only first file is created correctly

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV, sorted by values in column 0 (different locations), that I need to split into multiple files named after said value. i.e. location1.csv would contain all rows with location1, location2.csv would contain all rows with location2, etc.

I'm able to iterate and compare with a cursor just fine, but actually writing multiple CSVs is causing trouble.

```
with open(filepath) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    rows = list(csv_reader)

row_cur = 1 # assumes header
loc_cur = rows[1][0] # sets first location to be used as comparison
filecount = 0 # for naming output


for i in range(len(rows)-1):
    if rows[i+1][0] != loc_cur:
        print(loc_cur + ' != ' + rows[i+1][0]) # testing cursor compare
        with open(f'{filecount}_{loc_cur}.csv', 'w', newline='') as output:
            print(f'creating file: {output.name} from rows {row_cur} to {i}')
            csv_output = csv.writer(output)
            csv_output.writerows(rows[row_cur:i+1])
        row_cur = i+1
        loc_cur = rows[row_cur][0]
        filecount += 1

with open(f'{filecount}_{loc_cur}.csv', 'a', newline='') as output:
    print('creating file: ' + output.name + ' from rows ' + str(row_cur) + ' to ' + str(i))
    csv_output = csv.writer(output)
    csv_output.writerows(rows[row_cur:i + 1])
```

The first file comes out exactly as expected, 0_location1.csv, with all relevant rows. Every file after that isn't created properly; a unique blank file named 'location#' is created for each location with no errors.

Comment: Are you saying that, after the firt one, all of the file names are correct, but empty? And the debug prints are correct?

Comment: Running your code with my own sample data, I found that all files write correctly except the last one. I have a fix for that, but I don't think I've duplicated your problem so I am not answering the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

The `itertools` package in the standard library can make your job much easier. Since your rows are already sorted, you can use its `groupby` function to figure out the indexing for you.

```
import csv
import itertools

filepath = "i.csv"

with open(filepath, newline="") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    for index, (name, rows) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(csv_reader, lambda row: row[0])):
        with open(f"{index}_{name}.csv", "w", newline="") as output:
            csv.writer(output).writerows(rows)
```

and if you don't mind a dependency on the `pandas` package, you could do

```
import pandas as pd

filepath = "i.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
col0 = df.columns[0]
for index, (name, rows) in enumerate(df.groupby(col0, sort=False)):
    rows.to_csv(f"{index}_{name}.csv", header=None, index=False)
```

Comment: I'm still running into the same issue as with my original code, so I'm thinking it's probably some nonsense with my machine? Regardless, I appreciate the much more elegant code!

Answer (score 0):

tdlaney's solutions get the job done. If you'd like to see how to modify the code you have, read on.  The following approach also does **not** require that the CSV be presorted by the grouping value(s).

First we need to pick the data structure that represents the idea: "I want to group sets of rows by some value".  For me that simply looks like a dict with a string that keys those values to a list of rows.

If your CSV looked like:

```
Col1,Col2
loc1,a
loc1,b
loc1,c
loc2,d
loc3,e
loc3,f
```

then that dict looks like:

```py
{
    "loc1": [
        ["loc1", "a"],
        ["loc1", "b"],
        ["loc1", "c"],
    ],
    "loc2": [
        ["loc2", "d"],
    ],
    "loc3": [
        ["loc3", "e"],
        ["loc3", "f"],
    ],
}
```

A defaultdict works well for this.  (also, I like type hints, keeps me safe):

```py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import DefaultDict

Row = list[list[str]]  # create alias for "list of list of string"

groups: DefaultDict[str, Row] = defaultdict(Row)

with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)  # or just `next(reader)` to discard the header

    for row in reader:
        groups[row[0]].append(row)
```

From there, iterate the groups of keys and rows and write out the results:

```py
for i, (key, rows) in enumerate(groups.items(), start=1):
    fname = f"output_{i:>02}_{key}.csv"  # pad with 0 to two places

    with open(fname, "w", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(header)  # if you want it
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

and we get three files:

```
output_01_loc1.csv      output_02_loc2.csv      output_03_loc3.csv
```

If the CSV were not presorted, the order of the keys would most likely change, but the relative order of the grouped rows would reflect what was originally in the CSV:

```
Col1,Col2
loc2,d
loc1,a
loc3,e
loc1,b
loc1,c
loc3,f
```

will yield:

```py
{
    "loc2": [
        ["loc2", "d"],
    ],
    "loc1": [
        ["loc1", "a"],
        ["loc1", "b"],
        ["loc1", "c"],
    ],
    "loc3": [
        ["loc3", "e"],
        ["loc3", "f"],
    ],
}
```